# Display an NSSet/NSMutableSet of different objects in a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsset

i'm new to SOF and i hope this is a good question to begin with :)

i'm stuck with the following issue:

I need to display a NSMutableSet with the content of 2 different NSArrays containing 2 different object types in the same TableView and also in the same section.

I've tried with an NSMutableDictionary but couldn't figure out how to display the NSArrays stored into the dictionary, the first one and then the second within a sole section.

Thanks in advance.

PS: what i'm trying to do is to display entities like Meals, Foods and Drinks for a specific day in a tableView with grouped cell for each mealtime. So the grouped e.g. for a lunch shows 3 entities: meals, foods and drinks.

I'm getting NSSets of Meals, Foods, Drinks using a relationship to the Day Object. I tried to put them in an 2 dimensional array but failed on loading cells(it shows only the last object).

Comment: You need to supply more information. What kind of objects are we talking about. How are they arranged in the arrays and what are the rules for how they get displayed in the UI. If you have a screenshot of the UI that will help as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can ask the Object in the NSArray for its type with isa.
According to the answer you can prepare the cell in prepareForRowAtIndexpath

Comment: Rather than using `isa`, why not call `class` on the object in question?  What class defines the method `prepareForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers. I was trying to do this at a very late hour at night, i solved it. It was obvious. :P